# Why .Select changes Enumerable.Empty to System.Linq.EmptyPartition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Look at this example:

```
IEnumerable<string> en = Enumerable.Empty<string>(); //{string[0]}
var enSelected = en.Select(id => id);                //{System.Linq.EmptyPartition<string>}
var list = en as IList<object>;                      //{string[0]}
var listSelected = enSelected as IList<object>;      //null
```

Why using `.Select` on an empty enumerable changes its type? Could this be a bug in LINQ?

And what is even `System.Linq.EmptyPartition`? I did not find any documentation about this type and it is also not available directly in the code.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 15.4.2 and this is happening on a Xamarin.iOS project. Could you please test this on your environment so that we can see whether this is specific to my environment?

Comment: As @Timbo said. If you need list as the result use ToList() instead of _as_ operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declared return value of `Select` is `IEnumerable<T>`.

The actual type of the returned object is part of the implementation, and should never concern the user of the API.

Comment: Ok, the `as IList<object>` cast was actually part of a .Net ParseSDK (converting an object to Json). I added check `as IEnumerable<object>` as the last resort (after checking for string etc.) and it works. So, thanks for the answer, it is then probably not a LINQ bug, but still the `System.Linq.EmptyPartition` type is weird, never heard of it.

Comment: Except when it does. This is a breaking change in Core 3.0+ and does have side effects

Comment: @MichaelBrown No. Cross-casting references to interfaces they not implement by contract is just a wrong program, that has no guarantee to work.

Comment: Ideally you'd be correct, but this breaks things like JSON serialization